# Color interpolation (shader) does not work when using Matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I am trying to improve the quality of my plots in MATLAB and so I used Matlab2tikz to transform the MATLAB plots in `pgfplots`. I want to perform a color interpolation but this does not work and after browsing the `pgfplots` documentation and this website I couldn't find any solution.

Here is a code simplified from the original one to meet the MWE requirements.

```latex
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.983in,
height=3.141in,
at={(0.668in,0.693in)},
scale only axis,
point meta min=-10,
point meta max=200,
xmin=0,
xmax=2,
ymin=-1,
ymax=2,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={matlab2tikz plot},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black},
colorbar
]

\addplot[area legend, draw=none, table/row sep=crcr, patch, patch type=rectangle, shader=flat corner, patch table with point meta={%
0   1   4   5   -8\\
1   2   3   4   0\\
5   4   7   6   20\\
4   3   8   7   200\\
}]
table[row sep=crcr] {%
x   y\\
0   0\\
1   0\\
2   -1\\
2   0\\
1   1\\
0   1\\
0   2\\
1   2\\
2   1\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I tried to change `shader = flat corner` to `shader = interp` without success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I don't know what the result is supposed to be. However, Adobe Acrobat is generally the preferred viewer for these types of shadings. I see different results with your MWE when I view the pdf with Adobe versus Sumatra.

Comment: I want the result to be interpolated in the rectangles. I am doing my tests on overleaf exclusively so I use the builtin preview. I will try to open the pdf with other pdf viewers.

Comment: I expect the output to be like the third example of the 4.6.13  Patch Plots section in the documentation. This example works on my PDF viewer.